# Top tags within user profile is not user specific filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app, tag-search

When I click any tag in "Top Tags" it will filter the user's specific data.

[image]

Whereas in *Stack Exchange App* is not user specific.

[image]

Can we follow the same approach in both web and app?

Comment: I am not a smart man. I added this for a [meta-tag:feature-request] last month and didn't think it through, thanks for catching it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Its my Pleasure in helping you, BTW when will be 1.0.9 moved to prod/play store?

Comment: 1.0.9 has been out on the Play Store for around 6 hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.0.9 tapping on a tag on a user profile will navigate to a search of that user's interactions with that tag. Because the questions list currently only shows questions, not questions and answers like the site does, this search will only show questions they posted. When answers are brought onto that view (which is a [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)) it'll be 1-to-1 parity with the site.