# Searching by user id in Android app only shows questions, no answers

Tags: bug, android-app

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. Android version 4.3

I downloaded the official StackExchange app today. I am not able to view post related to android tag from my profile. I tried refreshing also

Snap

[image] [image]

Edit:

However i am able to see one post for the relevant from the drop down list

[image]

Edit 2:

I tried what Steven V suggested. However it's the same.

[image]

I tried for a different user its the same.

[image]

Comment: oh lawd dat font

Comment: No repo for me when I try this with my user. Or when I try it with your user. Any difference when you try `user:me [android]` as the search?

Comment: @StevenV its the same. wait i will post a snap of that also

Comment: @StevenV did you try it on samsung galaxy s3 or was it on a different device?

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm using a Nexus 5

Comment: @StevenV i tried with a different user its the same for Newest questions however i am able to see few posts for Relevant and Active tags fromt the drop down list.

Comment: Nothing to do with user id, just try to search `is:answer` and you'll get nothing at all!

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the vast majority of your posts on Stack Overflow in that tag are *answers* not questions. I hinted at this issue [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220309/229741) but I'm glad you reported it since this bug now has a real place to live.

What's happening here is that the website shows both questions and answers in search results, but the Android application only shows questions. Bringing answers into the search list is planned for the (hopefully near) future.

Comment: In 6-8 weeks? ;) All kidding aside, why would having many answers "drown out" the questions to return? I guess there's a limit that can be fetched each time (say, 15) and if your question is your 16th newest post in that tag, then it won't display?

Comment: When will future come? (2.5 years passed)

Comment: @Pandya never, as far as I can tell the app is discontinued. Not a single bug was fixed for about a full year.